# How to access all response times on every route in Express 4+?

Tags: node.js, performance, express

I'm struggling to pass response time data at the application-level to every route in my Express app. I've Googled and Googled but everything comes back suggesting one throw a `new Date()` into API calls, which is gross, or the Express [response-time](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time) package (including many results from here on SO). While I'm sure it's great, I don't understand what purpose it serves other than adding a header seeing as how I can get response times in my browser's dev tools.

What I *want* to do is access all response time data from the server into the view, on every route.

Express already provides *some* request data, but not all of it. I just can't seem to access all responses. My terminal looks like this when I load up a basic page, even though I have 6 images on the page besides the one CSS file.

`GET / 200 64.439 ms - 1663`
`GET /styles/index.css 200 36.582 ms - 2035`

If I use the response-time package, I can't seem to access the `'X-Response-time'`  header. `req.headers` only seems to return a subset of all headers, similar to the Express traffic output mentioned above.

Maybe I'm just dense, but even the docs of the response-time package mention how to [configure it with Express](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time#expressconnect), but I still don't understand what it's supposed to be adding or how I would access it outside of my console.

> Create a new middleware that records the response time of a request and makes this available to your own function fn. The fn argument will be invoked as fn(req, res, time), where time is a number in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do this:

```
var responseTime = require('response-time')
app.use(responseTime(function(req, res, time) {
    res.header('X-Response-Time', time);
}));
```

Now every route below this will have a response time header on it.

Comment: I'd be happy to expand on this answer... maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Re-read it. I have no problem setting headers. That's exactly what the response-time module does. I want to grab that data and inject it into the view.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. It always returns `undefined`.

Comment: Since you have the header you could inject your response time into the view on the client side. Would that be an acceptable option? Are you using any particular framework on the client side? (eg, angular, backbone, etc?)

Answer (score 0):

The `response-time` package will add the `X-Response-Time` header at the same time as you `send` the request:

```
app.use(responseTime());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
console.log(res.get('X-Response-Time')); // undefined
    res.send('Hello');
    console.log(res.get('X-Response-Time')); // 3.720ms
});
```

It does this by listening out for when headers are about to be written (e.g. when a request is about to be sent), appending the response time just before (using the `on-headers` package on npm).

It sounds like what you want to do is record the response time, then set it into `res.locals` so you can render it in your view.

I've played around for a while trying to use the `on-headers` package to set the response time inside `res.locals`, but I think it must be too late by then to write to the response... Maybe this is the right path? Sorry I don't have more time right now to play around :(